# PostgreSQL timestamp with negative

Tags: postgresql, type-conversion, timestamp

I have a set of date and time rows in varchar type which looks like this:

```
 |          TimeLocal          |
 | 2017-11-06 12:13:55 -21:18  |
 | 2017-11-06 12:18:50 -21:18  |
 | 2017-11-06 12:13:09 -21:18  |
```

I want to perform a conversion of this column into timestamp

```
 Select TimeLocal::timestamp as New_Time_Local From tb1
```

However I am getting this error

> ERROR: time zone displacement out of range

This appears only to those datetime with -21 but for the other dates, it was converted successfully

Any help would be much appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: and what time it actually is? `2017-11-06 12:13:55 -21:18`?.. is it a timezone minus 21 hour and 18 minutes?..

Comment: I'm not aware of any timezone being -21:18